# Are the size of tittles the same as the size of the full stop, or the dot in an exclamation mark?

Tags: punctuation, typography

As the title says: are the tittles the same size as the full stop, or the dots in an exclamation and question marks?  If they are different, is there any reason for this?

Comment: @YosefBaskin thank you.  Can you post a source?

Comment: This is purely a font question not an English question, since English is only one language using the Latin alphabet. And I’m not sure how the answer can be anything other than it depends on the specific font.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about fonts and not about English.

Comment: @Greybeard I understand, but is it not part of the typography category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your typeface or handwriting. There is no standardized ratio between [tittles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle) (a diacritic dot most commonly seen in English writing above the letters [i] and [j]), full stops, and other punctuation marks with dots in English written communication.

For instance, in Times New Roman, the tittle is slightly smaller than the full stop, though you may need good eyes to see it in smaller font.

[image: "ij.?!" in Times New Roman]

In Verdana, the full stop is bigger than the other marks, and the tittle may be slightly smaller than the question mark and exclamation point dot. Also, they're all boxes now.

[image: "ij.?!" in Verdana]

In Mistral, the tittles appear slightly larger and adopt irregular oblong shapes to resemble handwriting.

[image: "ij.?!" in Mistral]

You can experiment with handwriting and typeface to find the tittle size you prefer. Just be sure to explain what *tittle* means before you confess your preferences to others.